# How to pass data with server-side rendering to React-component from Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to pass some data to my components. I found this example: http://www.tech-dojo.org/#!/articles/56b1af3e8ff769fc29f96ae8
I have created a class DataWrapper which looks like in the example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class DataWrapper extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  getChildContext () {
    return {
      data: this.props.data
    };
  }

  render () {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

DataWrapper.childContextTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
    React.PropTypes.object,
    React.PropTypes.string
  ]).isRequired
};
```

Node-server:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
      ...
      const body = renderToString(
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={theme}>
          <DataWrapper data={'somedata'}>
            <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
          </DataWrapper>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      )
      res.render('index', { title, body })
```

And my component where I want to use the data looks like this:

```
export default class Template extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    console.log("Template context", context.data);
    ...
```

context.data is always undefined. What am I missing? Is there an other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If contextTypes is not defined, then context will be an empty object.`, quoting directly from React Docs. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#how-to-use-context

You will need to add

```
Template.contextTypes = {
    data: // whatever type it is
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've missed it.